# AngularJS - Is it clean to use $timeout to execute function after ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using `ngRepeat` directive to render a big data list and I'm using `$timeout` to execute a function after the `ng-repeat` if finished. It works well, but is it a proper way ?

I mean will it work for all the cases ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `$last` ($last = true if the repeated element is last in the iterator).

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <span ng-if="$last === true" ng-init="doSomething()"></span>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/by3qk8w5/2/

Answer (score 1):

I cant see your code, but I assume you just set the timeout to an arbitrary number to wait, which would mean you are basically just hoping that the ng-repeat will finish faster than that.

A proper solution would be to use the $last special property of the ng-repeat items, that is true when the last item of the ng-repeat list of items gets rendered. When it gets true, you execute your callback expression.

A complex solution using a custom directive can be found here for example:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2592-hooking-into-the-complete-event-of-an-ngrepeat-loop-in-angularjs.htm